# Java test fails (tostring)

Tags: java

I have this Java program, but my test gives me this message:

> testEmployeeTostring: failed testEmployeeTostring expected <[id[=
>   1013, name= Jubal Early, job = ]procurement]> but was: <[id[= 1013,
>   name= Jubal Early, job = ] procurement]>

I had to use `@Override` and I think that's the problem. I hope someone can figure out the problem with this:

```
public class Employee {

        int id;
        String name;
        JobType job;

        public Employee(int id, String name, JobType job)
        {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
                this.job = job;
        }

        @Override public String toString()
        {
                return ("["+ "id =" + id + ", name = "  + name + ", job = " + job + "]");
        }
}
```

Comment: override the equals() method as well?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the contribution. I didn't pay close attention to the spacing. I didn't know the test considered that a big deal. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have `equals()` method overriden? JUnit uses `equals()` to compare objects. Overriding `hashCode()` is always a good idea as well:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee) o;
    return id == employee.id && job == employee.job && name.equals(employee.name);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + job.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

The code above assumes all fields are non-nullable and that `JobType` is an `enum`. And BTW `toString()` might have nothing to do here, as long as you are comparing objects, not `toString()` of objects (bad practice).

Comment: This was my initial guess but it seems that the issue is different... Not worth a downvote in any case...

Answer (score 8):

There is a space between ] and 'procurement'

**job = ] procurement**

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra space in your expected String with the assertion statement.

Answer (score 1):

this probably happened due to JobType.toString() method returning an extra space.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have some extra space(s) in the string returned  toString() method thus making the returned string to be (slightly) different than the string the test expects.

Answer (score -1):

With `String a` and `String b`,

are you doing an `a == b` instead of `a.equals(b)` ?